# Sort-by-progress on A51 profiles isn't working right

Tags: bug, area-51, sorting

If you go to [Gilles's profile on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/18685/gilles) and look at his fulfilled commitments under the default sort order ("progress"), you see this:

[image]

This is incorrect - SF&F, having graduated should be at one end of the list or the other (above French would probably make the most sense, assuming that sites in public beta are sorted by days in beta).